# .Net 5 Check CustomPolicy from Razor Page

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization

I have a custom authorization handler as below:

```
public class CanApproveArticlesByOtherAuthorsClaimsHandler : AuthorizationHandler<ManageArticleApprovalRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, ManageArticleApprovalRequirement requirement)
    {
        var httpContext = context.Resource as HttpContext;

        if (httpContext == null)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        string loggedInUser = context.User.Claims
                                          .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
        string authorId = (string)httpContext.Request.RouteValues["authorid"];

        if (context.User.IsInRole("Admin")
            && context.User.HasClaim(claim => claim.Type == "Article Approver" && claim.Value == "true")
            && loggedInUser.ToLower() != authorId.ToLower())
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

I need to check if this policy is a success when I load `edit.cshtml` and determine if I need to load a control on the page. This is what I have now, but I want to use the custom policy.

```
        @if ((await authService.AuthorizeAsync(User, null, new[] { new ManageArticleApprovalRequirement() })).Succeeded)
    {
        <div class="col-sm-3 offset-sm-2">
            <input asp-for="@Model.Approved" class="form-check-input" />
            <label class="form-check-label" asp-for="@Model.Approved">Approve For Publication</label>
        </div>
    }
```

And in Startup.cs

```
            services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, CanApproveOnlyArticlesByOtherAuthorsHandler>();
```

and

```
            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            //Other code

            options.AddPolicy("ApproveArticlesPolicy", policy => policy.AddRequirements(new ManageArticleApprovalRequirement()));

            //Other code;

        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `IAuthorizationService` directly to authorize against a user with some requirement, like this:

```
@inject IAuthorizationService _authService;

<!-- the code section that need to authorize -->
<!-- for razor view, pass in Context instead of ViewContext.HttpContext 
     for the resource -->
@if((await _authService.AuthorizeAsync(User, ViewContext.HttpContext, new [] { new ManageArticleApprovalRequirement() })).Succeeded){
    <div class="col-sm-3 offset-sm-2">
        <input asp-for="@Model.Approved" class="form-check-input" />
        <label class="form-check-label" asp-for="@Model.Approved">Approve For Publication</label>
    </div>
}
```

Note I assume that your `ManageArticleApprovalRequirement` has a parameterless constructor. Basically you need to pass an instance of that requirement to the `IAuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync` method as the code above shows.

Comment: King King, thanks for the input and I think I am on the right path.  However, I may be doing something stupid.  I have put some break points and some log statements in the handler to capture what is happening as it is always failing, even on users it should be succeeding on, but the breakpoints and the log statements never get hit.

Also, I took your suggestion and put it in the controller and loaded a value in ViewBag to perform the same function.

Comment: Been tinkering with it all day.  Still no love.  Moved it back to the cshtml page, but no closer than that at this point.

Comment: @JayDavis have you registered your custom `IAuthorizationHandler`? like this `services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, CanApproveArticlesByOtherAuthorsClaimsHandler>()` (inside `Startup.ConfigureServices`)

Comment: LOL...yes...but typos matter....my bad.  I had renamed the handler to conform to some others and totally missed some changes.

Now I am hitting the handler, so progress!!  Now, however, the AuthorizationHandlerContext is coming in as null, I am assuming because I have not assigned this to a resource?

Comment: Any ideas on how to link the handler to the control in the cshtml?

Comment: @JayDavis the `context` passed in `HandleRequirementAsync` cannot be null. I think you mean its `context.Resource` which should be a `HttpContext`. Because of calling the `AuthorizeAsync` directly, you need to pass the `HttpContext` for its `resource` (the second arg which is passed in as `null` in my original code). You can pass in the `ViewContext.HttpContext` (in razor page) or `Context` (in razor view) instead of `null`. I've updated the answer as well.

Comment: That did it!  Thank you so much!